# how to fix footer at bottom gap without using height fixed?

Tags: html, css

I want to fix my footer at the bottom gap. I think content is less then this problem repeated and content full problem solved but I want to content less does not shows gap I'm using same footer remaining pages so help me any one.

[image]

Comment: Why not use `position:absolute;bottom:0;` on your footer?

Answer (score 0):

If content is less, why not simply fix it at the bottom. I mean its the dirtiest hack possible.

If you want something clean, look into sticky footer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
    function adjust(){
       var winH = $(window).height(),
           docH = $('document').height();

       if(docH > winH){
          //leave it
       }else{
         $('.footer').addClass('fix-footer');
       }
    }
    $(window).on('resize',adjust);
 })



 .fix-footer{position:fixed; bottom:0; left:0; width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is by using Flexbox. The flex property specifies how much the item will grow to fill up the remaining space.

The container needs to be set to `display: flex`, and we set `min-height: 100vh` for the body so that it fills up at least 100% of the viewport height.

CSS

```
body {
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
}
main {
    flex: 1;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <main>Main content goes here</main>
    <footer>Footer goes here</footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .main class as a container put all your body data in main container

```
  <html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body {
            margin:0;
            display: flex;
            height: 100vh;
            flex-direction: column;
            display:-ms-flexbox;
        }
        .main {
            flex: 1;

        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="main">Put you form here</div>
        <div class="footer">Footer goes here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="footer"></div>
```

css

```
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;     
}
```

**Position-absolute:**

This is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the location.

**Position-fixed:**

A fixed position element is positioned relative to the viewport, or the browser window itself. The viewport doesn't change when the window is scrolled, so a fixed positioned element will stay right where it is when the page is scrolled,

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11041824)

Comment: I have written css as an answer to stick footer at the bottom always.

Comment: Please add comments to let users understand "why" your solution could be a good one or maybe the best one. Posting only code is not enough